# Python inserting lists into a list with given length of the list

Tags: python, list

My problem is, that need a list with length of 6:

```
list=[[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Ok, that's not difficult. Next I'm going to insert integers into the list:

```
list=[[60],[47],[0],[47],[],[]]
```

Here comes the real problem: How can I now extend the lists and fill them again and so on, so that it looks something like that:

```
list=[[60,47,13],[47,13,8],[1,3,1],[13,8,5],[],[]]
```

I can't find a solution, because at the beginning i do not know the length of each list, I know, they are all the same, but I'm not able to say what length exactly they will have at the end, so I'm forced to add an element to each of these lists, but for some reason i can't.

Btw: This is not a homework, it's part of a private project :)

Comment: `array.extend` or `array.append` would probably be benificial ... however it is hard to understand what your inputs and expected outputs are ..

Comment: Please don't use `list` to name your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. You use normal list operations to add elements.

```
L[0].append(47)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the name `list` for your variable it conflicts with the built-in function `list()`

```
my_list = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]
my_list[0].append(60)
my_list[1].append(47)
my_list[2].append(0)
my_list[3].append(47)
print my_list # prints [[60],[47],[0],[47],[],[]]
```